# “Open the current folder in Explorer” in TexMaker?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, tex, texmaker

Many IDEs natively provide a way to easily open the current folder in Explorer. Is there any way to do this in TexMaker?

E.g. in Microsoft Visual Studio, I use:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the same feature. Texmaker doesn't have a built-in functionality regarding this issue, however, in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321984/does-texmaker-have-open-containing-folder-option), you can customize user's commands to allow explorer to open a containing folder.